# Apachesolr Subquery error in drupal 7

Tags: apache, drupal, solr, drupal-7

I am working on apachesolr search module in drupal 7 I want to retrieve results based on two conditions. I have created solr search query i passed 60 taxonomy terms into subquery to search am getting empty result.

**Query function**

```
$geography= new SolrFilterSubQuery('OR');
foreach($geographies as $c_geography) {
$geography_filter->addFilter('target_geographies', $c_geography);
}

$d_filter = new SolrFilterSubQuery('OR');
foreach($c_diseases as $c_disease) {
$d_filter->addFilter('field_disease', $c_disease);
}
$compiled_filter = new SolrFilterSubQuery('AND');
$compiled_filter->addFilterSubQuery($geography_filter);
$compiled_filter->addFilterSubQuery($d_filter);
$g_filter->addFilterSubQuery($compiled_filter);

$query->addFilterSubQuery($g_filter);
```

**Result**

```
stdClass Object
(
[data] =>

001.01.01.01.01.01.01.01.01.01.0

[protocol] => HTTP/1.1
[code] => 200
[status_message] => OK
[headers] => Array
(
[Transfer-Encoding] => chunked
[X-Hyperion-Response] => 1
[Server] => Apache-Coyote/1.1
[Connection] => close
[X-Pantheon-Host] => indexserver-9bdfba0f.c.pantheon-dmz.internal
[Date] => Wed, 18 Jul 2018 09:52:04 GMT
[Content-Type] => application/xml;charset=UTF-8
)
```

)

Comment: Check what the actual query being sent to Solr is - I'm not familiar with the Drupal Solr module, but you can turn on logging on the Solr side to INFO level, and it'll show all queries being made. That'll help to see where the issue might be.

Comment: What is the init of `$g_filter` ?

Comment: It's generating subquery content.